# CocoaLumberjack - Swift : Not getting Previous Days Log Files

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

I am using `CocoaLumberjack/Swift` Pod in my **iOS** project.

The problem is, I am getting always **Current day(Today or Last day of last time app launched)** log files. **CocoaLumberjack** doesn't keeping old log files of **Previous days**.

> For me Today is **2020-02-19**. And the files I get from **CocoaLumberjack**:
>
> xyz **2020-02-19**--05-55-39-774.log // file size -> 10 MB
>
> xyz **2020-02-19**--05-55-46-305.log // file size -> 1.7 MB
>
> > ** There are no older files from previous days

I disabled Time Based Rolling.

`logger.rollingFrequency = -1 // also tried with 0`

And Use 10 MB memory limit for each file

`logger.maximumFileSize = 10 * (1024 * 1024) //10MB`

According the **CocoaLumberjack** document.

```
* You may optionally disable rolling due to filesize by setting `maximumFileSize` to zero.
* If you do so, rolling is based solely on `rollingFrequency`.
```

Here is my source code from **AppDelegate**.

```
import CocoaLumberjack

...... 

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Enable CocoaLumberjack logging
    self.setLoggingProperty()
}

private func setLoggingProperty() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        DDLog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        DDLog.add(DDASLLogger.sharedInstance)
        if let dDTTYLogger = DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance {
            DDLog.add(dDTTYLogger)
        }
    }

    let logger: DDFileLogger = DDFileLogger.init()

    logger.maximumFileSize = 10 * (1024*1024) //10MB
    logger.rollingFrequency = -1 // Disable time base rolling

    logger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
    DDLog.add(logger)
}
```

Does anyone faces similar issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: **Note**
I previously tried with daily rolling frequency. That time also getting same issue.

```logger.rollingFrequency = 24 * 60 * 60```

Answer (score 1):

change the rolling frequency and size. Sets the bellow snippet

```
let fileLogger = DDFileLogger(logFileManager: LogsManager.shared())
        DDLog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance)
        // 24-hour rolling, maximum 14 files, max 50 MB per file.
        fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24
        fileLogger.maximumFileSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024;
        fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 14;
        // The file logger
        DDLog.add(fileLogger)
        // TTY = The Xcode console logger
        DDLog.add(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance)
        // ASL = The Apple System Logs
        DDLog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance)
```

Comment: Tried that too. That one is also not working. Thus I disabled daily rolling, so that atleast we get more logs from last log file.

Comment: so you disable rolling due to time by setting `rollingFrequency` -1 that's why rolling is  now based on  `maximumFileSize`, so increase the file size to maximum.

Comment: Right. But the problem is, I didn't getting old log files. I should get max 7 (```maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7```) last log files from log directory. But only getting current day created log files.